# Display Watch Face in android activity

Tags: android, wear-os

I'd like to display a watch face I've developed in my app and have it appear live as though it was on a watch. The class and engine already exist so i feel like it shouldn't be too hard to get it to appear within an activity. Does anyone have experience with this or have a suggestions as to which path to take in attempting this?

Comment: Your question is unclear - what is your watch face exactly? Is it a `View` of some sort? If not, what does it derive from?

Comment: It is implemented as a watch face in the same way shown in the sample linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly easy to achieve. What you need to do is this:

1. extract all the drawing logic; which is whatever code is interacting with `Canvas`.
2. create a custom `View` and in [View.onDraw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) use the extracted code to draw the watch face.

In the end everything draws on a `Canvas`, so you can (more or less) transfer functionality from `View` objects to `WallpapersService`. `View` system is an abstraction on top of `Canvas`.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by:  "so you can (more or less) transfer functionality from View objects to WallpapersService"

Comment: What I mean is that you View.onDraw uses a Canvas. So, if you have code that draw on Canvas, your view.onDraw method can just use this code. And, if you havea wallpaper, you can take a view, lay it out and then call view.draw(canvas) and get the drawing. Views are just a layer on top of Canvas.

Comment: Got it, yeah I used your suggestion (along with looking at the google training on custom views) and got it to work! Now i'd just need to figure out how to clip the corners so that it's perfectly round watch face.